# problem from Kenneth Rosen's Discrete Mathematics and its Applications, Section 1.5

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, quantifiers

> Express this system specifications using predicates, quantifiers, and
>   logical connectives, if necessary.
>
> There are exactly two systems that monitor every remote server.

*My solution is :*

> **∃x∃y∀z(x != y ∧ (∀s M(z,s) → (z = x ∨ z = y)))**, where M(a, b) means that system a monitors remote server b

*So can anyone please check my solution if it's correct and if not what is the correct solution?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem:

> There are exactly two systems that monitor every remote server.
>
> M(a, b) means that system **a** monitors remote server **b**.

Can be rewritten into:

$\color{red}{\text{There is a system x and there is a system z such that the two systems are different}}$ and $\color{blue}{\text{system x monitors all remote servers and system z monitors all remote servers}}$ and $\color{green}{\text{no other system w monitors all remote servers}}$.

$$\color{red}{\exists x,z(x\neq z} \land \color{blue}{\forall y M(x,y) \land \forall y M(z,y)}\land \color{green}{\lnot\exists w(w \neq x \land w \neq z \land \forall y M(w,y))}\color{red}{)}$$

Since $\lnot\exists w(P(w)) \iff \forall w(\lnot P(w))$, we can rewrite this as:

$$\color{red}{\exists x,z(x\neq z} \land \color{blue}{\forall y M(x,y) \land \forall y M(z,y)}\land \color{green}{\forall w(\underbrace{w = x \lor w = z}_{\psi} \lor \lnot\underbrace{\forall y M(w,y)}_{\phi})}\color{red}{)}$$

Finally, using the property:

$\psi \lor \lnot\phi \iff \phi\rightarrow \psi$

we end up with the accepted solution:

$$\color{red}{\exists x,z(x\neq z} \land \color{blue}{\forall y M(x,y) \land \forall y M(z,y)}\land \color{green}{\forall w(\forall y M(w,y) \rightarrow (w = x \lor w = z))}\color{red}{)}$$

Answer (score 1):

The valid [solution](https://www.slader.com/discussion/question/b-there-is-a-student-in-this-class-who-owns-a-personal-computer-c-every-student-in-this-class-has-ta/#) is:

> **∃x∃y((x ≠ y) ∧ ∀zM(x,z) ∧ ∀zM(y,z) ∧ ∀w(∀zM(w,z) → (w = x) ∨ (w = y)))**

And so my solution is too close to the right I just missed to put **∀zM(x,z) ∧ ∀zM(y,z)**

Comment: In case you still want a formal proof for this, I think [I finally got it](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3603903/716144). Also, thanks for letting me know when I was wrong. I have learned a couple of important things I didn't know before.

Comment: Thanks alot for your efforts to help me .. really happy for that discussion dear @mateleco